# Viewing supply point cases at a supervisory level

Tags: commcare

How do you view `supply-point` cases for an organization lower in the hierarchy of a organization structure?

I have set up a CommCare supply app using the organizations structure and levels. I've marked the lowest level in the organization structure as "Tracks stock" in order to force that level to create cases associated with each location. When I click on any location in that level I now see "View location case" when I edit that location, therefore I know the supply-point cases are being created. However when I log in as the supervisory level for that same location on WebApps, I cannot see those supply point cases.

I thought perhaps the issue was that the supervisory level for that location wasn't correctly configured, however that level is configured to "View child data" So that hypothesis was ruled out.

Then I thought perhaps the issue was that the case type was incorrectly configured for the module, however the case type for the module is `supply-point` so it also looks to be configured correctly.

Case sharing is also already enabled for this application, so that has also been ruled out as the potential blocker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using organization-based case sharing, any location levels whose cases you want to be shared need to be tagged as "owns cases".

The same rules apply to CommCare Supply. The supply points are associated with the location level they sit at, so any supply points you want to be available to supervisors must be assigned to a location type that "owns cases".

So in your scenario the lowest level of the hierarchy should also be tagged with this flag. Can you double check that it is? I believe changing this setting from the Organization Levels page should fix it.